# Why doesnt java tcp socket send all data when called repeatetly in a while-loop?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am sending data over a socket but the java socket seems to change ordering and loose data and I can't fix it.
Here is my java code:

```
Socket socket;
...
while(isSending){
  try {
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    String data = getMyData();
    out.writeBytes(data);//data is a csv string parsed on server-side
    out.flush();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Server.cpp:

```
while(1){
    char recv_buffer[4096];
    memset(recv_buffer,0,4096);
    //receive data from socket
   int ret = recv(socket , recv_buffer , 4095 , 0);
   if (ret == 0){
      error_print("Socket not connected");
      ret = 0;
   } else if (ret < 0) {
      error_print("Error reading from socket!");
      ret = 0;
   }
  if(ret<=0) break;
  recv_buffer[ret]='\0';

  //parse recv_buffer
}
```

If I put a Thread.sleep(2000) in the java while-loop, the values are received correctly. What could be the reason for this behavior and how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you are not getting data from stream as quickly as you are sending.

Comment: You should show the code that is reading the data.

Comment: @DarshanLila Isn't that EXACTLY what should NOT happen when using TCP sockets?

Comment: It does send all the data. The Java API and Posix require it. Your *receiving* code is where the bug is. Post it (edited into your question) and we'll show you where.

Comment: @DarshanLila TCP provides flow control. Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP Ok surely. I didn't read the question carefully. I thought the user is reading the data from stream and than writting.

Comment: @user2212461 Somewhat difficult to believe. You must have had a `BufferedOutputStream` in the stack somewhere.

Comment: @DarshanLila Your comment still doesn't make sense. This code can't send to a TCP stream any faster than the receiver is reading.

Comment: @EJP you are not getting what I am saying.

Comment: @DarshanLila Nobody could. What you're saying doesn't make sense. Try again.

Comment: @EJP Hm in fact I still have the same problem, I post my server code

Comment: `recv()` returning zero doen't mean 'socket not connected': it means the peer disconnected. I don't see anything else wrong with your current code. What does 'parse `recv_buffer`' do exactly?

Comment: thanks for the explanation. the parser uses std::getline to separate the input but that shouldn't be the problem, because when I printf just the whole received buffer, already some parts are missing

Comment: You're going to have to provide more detail than that. TCP doesn't lose data. You are undoubtedly receiving everything and then misusing it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Just as I suspected. You are completely ignoring the value returned by the recv() function. It can be -1 indicating an error, or zero indicating end of stream, or a positive integer indicating the length received. Instead you are assuming not only that the read aucceeded but also that it returns a null-terminated string.

Comment: I added the detailed server code. If you know where in the code the reason for the in the question stated problem lies, please share.